# Use different ip addresses in puppeteer requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, chromium, puppeteer

I have multiple ip interfaces in my server and I can't find how to force puppeteer to use them in its requests

I am using node v10.15.0 and puppeteer 1.11.0

Comment: How would you force an IP interface in your Chrome app?

Comment: @hardkoded I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: Puppeteer talks to a Chrome browser instance. If you can't force an interface in Chrome you won't be able to do that using Puppeteer. If you can do that in Chrome we could see if that's feasible.

Comment: did you ever get this to work. I am having the same issue.

Comment: @Jamesed no i didn't find a solution so I worked without it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the flag `--netifs-to-ignore` when launching the browser to specify which interfaces should be ignored by Chrome. Quote from the [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/):

> **--netifs-to-ignore**: List of network interfaces to ignore. Ignored interfaces will not be used for network connectivity

You can use the argument like this when launching the browser:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--netifs-to-ignore=INTERFACE_TO_IGNORE']
});
```

Comment: I tried to get this to work but it doesnt seem to be ignoring the specified interface. I am assuming that INTERFACE_TO_IGNORE is the interface name correct? I couldnt find a good example of how to use it.   For example --netifs-to-ignore=eth0

Comment: @Jamesed Yes, I assume that would be how to use it. But I have never used it myself, just found it in the flag list. Sorry.

Comment: thanks.  I realized after sometime that specific flag works only on linux and not mac

Comment: I don't think this works. I filed a bug report here https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6744

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help. You can see the full code [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/examples/proxy.js)

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    // Launch chromium using a proxy server on port 9876.
    // More on proxying:
    //    https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings
    args: [ '--proxy-server=127.0.0.1:9876' ]
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://google.com');
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: This is proxy setting which is not quite the same as using different IPs accessible to one host machine without extra hops.